# how do you remove a letter from a string when using substring

Tags: java

So I am trying to remove all the x's from this string! Of course I can use replaceAll but I want it to remove one by one each x and then print it! But it keeps either erroring out or I just can't seem to remove it! Of course I know how to find the x but idk how to remove afterwards!

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message = "Ix lovex youxxx";
        System.out.println(message);
        for(int x = 0 ; message.length() > 0 ; x++){
            String v = message.substring(x, x+1);
            if (v.indexOf("x") > -1){
                String w = message.substring(v, v+1);
            }
            System.out.println(message);
        }
       


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could work with `StringBuilder`, which has an inbuilt method `deleteCharAt`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String msg = "Ix lovex youxxx";
    char toExtract = 'x';
    StringBuilder sb;

    System.out.println(msg);
    
    while (msg.indexOf(toExtract) != -1) {
        sb = new StringBuilder(msg);
        int index = msg.indexOf(toExtract);
        sb.deleteCharAt(index);
        msg = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(msg);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Ix lovex youxxx
I lovex youxxx
I love youxxx
I love youxx
I love youx
I love you
```

Explanation:

As long as the string `msg` still has the character to extract, a `StringBuilder` is made containing the current message, the first index is removed and then saved back to `msg` and printed.

Answer (score 0):

Try `replaceFirst`, replace the x's one by one from left, like below:

```
public class Test1
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String message = "Ix lovex youxxx";
        System.out.println(message);
        while(message.indexOf("x")>0)
        {
            message = message.replaceFirst("x", "");
            System.out.println(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
Ix lovex youxxx
I lovex youxxx
I love youxxx
I love youxx
I love youx
I love you
```